# What is exactly meant by the term "API client"

Tags: api, terminology, client

I'm reading Robert Sedgewick's Algorithms book and I often see the term API client. Please take a look at this exercise:

> Write an iterable Stack client that has a static method copy() that takes a stack
>   of strings as argument and returns a copy of the stack. Note : This ability is a prime
>   example of the value of having an iterator, because it allows development of such functionality
>   without changing the basic API.

I'm confused as to whether he wants me to implement the Stack API by creating a concrete class that implements Stack or he wants me to write a program that uses the Stack API functionality. So does he want this

```
class StackImpl implements Stack<Item>{
}
```

or this?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    stack.push("to");
    stack.push("be");
    stack.push("or");
    stack.push("not");
    System.out.println(copy(stack));
}

public static Stack<String> copy(Stack<String> stack){
     //copy from stack to a new stack and return
}
```

Comment: A *client* of X is always a component that *uses* X, so it's the second alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an API, the client is any code that makes use of the functionality offered by the API.

I haven't read the book, but:

- the second option seems definitively to comply with the exercise: you have some code that implements a `copy()` that relies on the use of API functions to perform its duties, and on top of that you provide some demo code that shows how to use `copy()` with the API.
- the first option considers `Stack` to be an interface. This would mean that there is no `Stack` implementation, but that on contrary, you have to provide the API.  So you would make a provider/an implementation of the API and not a client.